# Alert Issue on Strategy Using Alternate Source Equations

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My strat applies its rules to alternate source data, an equation of symbols. (As opposed to price).

But alerts aren't surfacing properly.

Because, as I just learned, equations of symbols are built off of tick data combined from different servers, and thus it repaints.

Is there any workaround for this?

For instance, can tick data be converted into OHLC bars inside the script, with calculations performed on the OHLC bars?